# How to add sortby and direction as query parameter in Fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

I am new to FastAPI and APIs in general. I am trying to work on an online assignment by Hatchway.io where I have to fetch data from a link you can find instructions here: https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/instructions/b-3/Back-end%20Assessment%20-%20Blog%20Posts-TZW3TH2D4VFVDPKH4D6C.pdf.
I am almost done except the part where I need to ad sortby and direction as query parameters.

In `sortBy` I should be able to pass string like `sorBy=likes` and the results are sorted according to the number of likes

In `direction` I should be able to pass `direction=desc` or `asc` so that the posts can be arranged according to the number of likes in descending or ascending order.

eg:
https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/solution/posts?tags=history,tech&sortBy=id&direction=asc

Also it says **Please dont call this API in your application** above the example link. I dont understand what they mean by that.

Here is my code so far:

main.py:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
import fastapi
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
import data


app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
def root():
    return{'message': 'Hello World'}


@app.get('/api/tags')
async def tags(tags: str):
    posts = await data.get_tags(tags)
    if not posts:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404)

    return posts
```

data.py:

```
import httpx

async def get_tags(tags: str):
    url= f'https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/blog/posts?tag={tags}'


    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        resp = httpx.Response = await client.get(url)
        resp.raise_for_status()

        data = resp.json()

    results = data['posts']
    if not results:
        return None

    return results
```

Comment: "Please do not call this API in your application" .. they mean that you should _NOT_ call that API in your application, which is what you do. You should _replicate_ an API that returns the same kind of response, not call the API that gives the correct result already.

Comment: Okay that was what I was thinking but what do this mean then:
**You will be building an API that requires you to fetch data from this API:**
https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/blog/posts
I know my questions might sound dumb but I am super new to apis and I am teaching myself with some tutorials and documentaion.

Answer (score 1):

When working with FastAPI and handling query parameters for ordering data fetched from a database, you can follow these best practices:

**Enum for Ordering Fields:** Use an enumeration to define allowed ordering fields to prevent arbitrary values and to improve security.

Here's an example implementation of these best practices:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Depends
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from typing import List
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel

# Assuming you have an SQLAlchemy model named "Post"
from models import Post
from database import get_db

app = FastAPI()


class OrderBy(str, Enum):
    id = "id"
    name = "name"
    created = "created"


class ItemQueryParams(BaseModel):
    order_by: OrderBy = OrderBy.id
    descending: bool = False


@app.get("/posts/", response_model=List[Post])
def get_posts(
    skip: int = Query(0, alias="page", description="Page number"),
    limit: int = Query(10, description="Posts per page"),
    params: ItemQueryParams = Depends(),
    db: Session = Depends(get_db),
):
    order_column = getattr(Post, params.order_by)
    if params.descending:
        order_column = order_column.desc()

    posts = db.query(Post).order_by(order_column).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()
    return posts
```

[Swagger UI.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GSGs.png)